# Failed to open service <OracleOraDb10g_home1TNSListener>, error 1060

Tags: oracle

I am not able to start my oracle database listener.
It display the following error message:

Failed to open service , error 1060.
TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Log messages written to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\log\listener.log

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the log? Is your database started? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My database is started but i am unable to start the listener.

Comment: Copied from Microsoft System Error Codes.   ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST  1060 (0x424)
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's something like the port is already being used by another process.  The database doesn't have to be running to start the listener so that wouldn't cause it to fail.  Posting the end of the log would make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when I rebuilt a database server.  Another possibility, specific to windows, is a registry setting is incorrect.  In my case, it was as simple as TNS_ADMIN pointing to the wrong location.